# No bootable device found on bootable USB

Tags: uefi

I would like to install Ubuntu with a USB which was prepared with UUI, but it says "No bootable device found. Insert a bootable device and try again." I tried the exact same thing before on my previous laptop and it worked just fine. My laptop is an HP 15 Notebook PC. My previous laptop was also an HP 15 Notebook PC, but had lower specifications. I checked and my laptop is UEFI just like my previous one. Any and all help is appreciated.

Comment: Did you try to mount Ubuntu in the USB again? Or maybe a different portable drive?

Comment: Yes, infact I have tried to mount lots of different Ubuntu distributions to this USB drive. This is the only USB drive I own.

Comment: Maybe you could try with a DVD?

Comment: I do not have a DVD big enough for Ubuntu. The only thing I have is this 32gb USB which has worked wonderfully in the past.

Comment: Some work better if UEFI Secure Boot is off. But installer should boot in UEFI with Secure Boot, standard UEFI, and BIOS/CSM modes if correctly configured. You may also have to turn on allow USB boot in UEFI. Also until configured turn off UEFI fast boot. What model HP?

Comment: HP Pavilion Notebook PC. When I turn Legacy Boot on (so it shows the USB in boot options), it automatically disables Secure Boot. Allow USB is on.

Answer (score 1):

I fixed it by downloading Rufus (Windows), selecting the USB and the ISO for Ubuntu, and clicked Start, and it worked wonderfully.

Comment: To create a good answer you really should tell what you did and how you did it.